# Cannot access server through SSH, but nothings changed

Tags: linux, ssh

I've always been able to log into my dedicated server through the terminal (Mac) with the standard `root@my.ip.address` and then enter my root password (obviously I've replaced my actual IP address throughout this post with my.ip.address)

Today I tried and got `Permission denied, please try again.`, so I double checked with my host company that my root password hadn't changed, and it hasn't, so I tried again and got `Permission denied (publickey,password).` and so I tried the verbose explanation `ssh -vvv root@my.ip.address and got the following:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to my.ip.address [my.ip.address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/helenlucyburns/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/helenlucyburns/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/helenlucyburns/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/helenlucyburns/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/helenlucyburns/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

And now all I can get is that last line `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

Nothing has changed on the server, the root password was definitely correct and I'm the only one that has access to change anything (and I haven't). I only deal with SSH when I absolutely have to so don't understand anything very technical and this has stumped me... I can't even get in!!

Does anyone have any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

That "connection reset" is just about the spot that a server would disconnect due to TCP Wrappers, DenyHosts, or something similar. Hopefully, your address isn't triggering that... I know a failed reverse DNS lookup on your client IP can cause a failure at this point with some combination of server options (although I don't know off the top of my head which combination that is.) In any event, the actual reason for your troubles is likely to be contained in the /var/log/secure log file on your server, which you can't get to without being able to log in... I would suggest contacting support and asking them to grab that file for you and emailing it to you. Once you get that file, I suspect the answer will be obvious.

Comment: I am self-managed so they won't help. I never need them, and if I do then I have a guy that does all that stuff for me, but I didn't ever think I simply wouldn't be able to log in!!